# REST api is not calling from client to webservice

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have created a `Jersey REST` webservice `'RegisterService'` with a `POST` method. I would like to receive values for `'name'`, `'email'`, `'company'` in `'RegisterClientPost'` class and insert these value into database and send back as `JSON` response. 
Can someone please help, how to call the api from client and pass back to service level ?

```
Tomcat Server v7.0
Jersey (jaxrs-ri-2.25.1) 
MySQL 5 + version


@Path("/register")
public class RegisterService {
    private static final String REST_URI = "http://localhost:8080/MyFirstJavaTest/rest/register/postPlayer";  
    private Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();      
    @POST
    @Path("/postPlayer")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createJsonPlayer(WeekendPlayer player) {
    return client
      .target(REST_URI)
      .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .post(Entity.entity(player, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }
}
```

**//How to get the Player values in 'RegisterClientPost'and insert into database, pass into json object and return back to 'RegisterService'**

```
public class RegisterClientPost {   
    public static void main(String[] args) {                 

            try {           

            String t_Name ="Apple Mango";
            String t_Email ="test@example.com";
            String t_Comp ="Test Ltd";

            Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            WebTarget webTarget 
              = client.target("http://localhost:8080/MyFirstJavaTest/rest");
            WebTarget employeeWebTarget 
              = webTarget.path("/register/postPlayer");
            Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder 
              = employeeWebTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);          
            Response response 
              = invocationBuilder
              .post(Entity.entity(inputJson, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));              

            if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + response.getStatus());
            }          

            con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

}
```

**// Model class with getters and setters**

```
public class WeekendPlayer {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String company; 

    public WeekendPlayer()
    {

    }

    public WeekendPlayer(String name, String email, String company)
    {
    super();


    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.company = company;


    }    

    public String getName()
    {
    return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
    this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
    return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
    this.email = email;
    }
....

}
```

// **Web.xml** used

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Register Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.myfirstjavatest.pkg</param-value>        
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Register Service</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Error received in **postman:**
The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method.

Comment: your resource defines `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)` but your client sends `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`. Change it to `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Comment: @saw303 maybe better to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your resource definies the following method that expected a HTTP POST of an URL encoded form (See `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)`)

```
@POST
@Path("/postPlayer")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createJsonPlayer(WeekendPlayer player) {
    return Response.ok();
}
```

But your JAX-RS client sends the HTTP POST with `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON`. This is why you get the error. You need to change the annotation to `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

```
@POST
@Path("/postPlayer")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createJsonPlayer(WeekendPlayer player) {
    return Response.ok("It works!");
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error after changing to @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) in postman. Restarted the server.

Comment: HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type. The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method

Comment: how do you pass your param?

Comment: String inputJson = "{\"email\": \"test@example.com\", \"name\": \"Apple Mango\", \"company\": \"Test Ltd\"}";

Comment: @soccerway you are aware that that is nowhere in the code you posted in your question?

Comment: @Stultuske:  Now 'nothing' is displaying under Pretty, Raw,  Preview tab in postman. But the status seems to be 200 Ok

Comment: Yes, I understand that, my bad, missed while copying to stack overflow

Comment: @soccerway 200 OK means it is working since my example simply returns a `return Response.ok();` which is a HTTP 200 response without a body. Can you therefore accept my answer or do you need further assistance?

Comment: @Saw303:  But I am not able to get any data as response, do you why the client is not sending the json object back in postman. Also when do I need to do the insert the data into MySQL

Comment: What would you like to return when you create a WeekendPlayer. This is not clear. You can insert you `WeekendPlayer` players to a database when your resource method `createJsonPlayer` is called

Comment: Accepted your answer, one last question can i receive values using  @FormParam in 'RegisterClientPost' and strore those in an array or map, then use Gson to convert them jsonObject. Later pass the json object back to resourceMethod createJsonPlayer ?